# Mock Postman request into Axios?

Tags: reactjs, api, react-native, axios, postman

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to construct my `axios` to be able to mimic the postman request but failed. Please help to have a look

```
const ax = axios.create({
  timeout: 30000,
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
});

// Attempt register operation
ax.post('https://url/5bc9ff9628d79b6d274165da/update.json', {
  body: JSON.stringify({
    json: JSON.stringify({ "stat": "Delivered" })
  })
})
.then(({ data }) => {
  console.log('DEBUG::success!!! data::', data);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('DEBUG::err', err);
});
```

Comment: can you show headers screenshot as well

Comment: @Goldy: Please take a look. The remaining two key will be hiding as it's some secret key which I dont think needed in this question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can make use of the code-generation feature in Postman.

[image]
Click on Code (below Save button) > Search for 'Axios' > NodeJS - Axios

[image: postman code gen supports axios now]

Docs for code generation in Postman: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/

Comment: Didn't know there is such great feature! Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 9):

## 2022 Update

1. Click on `</>` icon in right side nav bar

[image]

2. Select Axios from drop down

[image]