# API works with Postman, but not Axios

Tags: rest, axios, postman

I am trying to get data from a 3rd-party API, but cannot get any data back from it in my program. However, I can get it to work via Postman.

params in Postman:
[image: params in Postman]

JSON from Postman:
[image: JSON from Postman]

JSON from console:
[image]

the code in question:

```
const consola = require('consola');
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');

const app = express();

// GET - /api/title
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

  const title = 'and then there were none'; // this is just until data is coming from user input

  const replaceSpaces = (str) => str.split(' ').join('+');

  axios
    .get('https://tastedive.com/api/similar', {
      params: {
        q: replaceSpaces(title),
        type: 'books',
        info: 1,
        limit: 7,
        k: process.env.TASTE_DIVE_KEY,
      },
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
      consola.ready({
        message: `data from axios server ${JSON.stringify(data)}`,
        badge: true,
      });
      res.json(data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      res.status(400).json(error);
      consola.error({
        message: `error from axios server ${error}`,
        badge: true,
      });
    });
});
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this discrepancy? I have the same params in both my code and in Postman, but I'm not getting the full data back in my app that I am in Postman.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53667487/5764220
If it doesn't help you, let me know and I'll look into it.

Comment: How about `replaceSpaces` method? Maybe you it is not returning correct data? Or `process.env.TASTE_DIVE_KEY` maybe is wrong? Try to console.log them two.

Comment: Sivcan- I'll give it a try. Looks interesting. On my phone at this point, so I'll have to get back to you about it tomorrow.

Comment: robmax- I did double check both of those and they are returning what I'm expecting.

Comment: Sivcan- the code generation feature in postman didn't give me anything that I didn't already have in my code.