# Pass key and value in Axios request NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, http-headers

**Actions**
This is my axios request

```js
import axios from 'axios';
export default axios.create(
        {
            baseURL: 'https://netsocial-838923.uc.r.appspot.com/api/v1/products',
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOdjfdkfiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZmEwMWMzZmM4YjIwfdkjdfjjBjZDQyMmJkNzUdkfjjfdsfjdiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDQ0MTAwMDZ9.xZU6RZgj5D8u1cqlSYv5mkdHn8-SnW0KwFAgVtsJUQw',
            }
        }
);
```

**Expected:**
I want to do something like I tested on Postman using `key=x-auth-token` &
`value=mytokenvalue-dkjfdkf-dfkdjfd`
[image]

**Output:** 
But I keep getting status 400

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create(
        {
            baseURL: 'https://netsocial-838923.uc.r.appspot.com/api/v1/products',
            headers: {
                'x-auth-token': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOdjfdkfiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZmEwMWMzZmM4YjIwfdkjdfjjBjZDQyMmJkNzUdkfjjfdsfjdiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDQ0MTAwMDZ9.xZU6RZgj5D8u1cqlSYv5mkdHn8-SnW0KwFAgVtsJUQw',
            }
        }
);
```

Also, I can see there is not Bearer used. If not remove from token. or else keep the bearer as it is.

You need to change header name to the name which API is looking for.

Comment: Thank for answer, however it is not working 401 status code,but I did test that token on Postman and it works fine. response: {data: "Access denied. No token provided.", status: 401, statusText: undefined, headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
toJSON: ƒ ()

Comment: Hmm Strange. Do one thing. there should be a option to copy code of postman to axios. Try with that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667206/mock-postman-request-into-axios
Check this.