# What should I do in my Node app when access token to Imgur API is expired?

Tags: node.js, rest, postman, access-token

Imgur API, as every other API, requires an access token. I get it through their original collection of API inside Postman. Though I may not set access token inside my Node app, all HTTP requests calls just work, I do not completely understand why.

What should I need to do to refresh my access token once it is expired **without manually touching Postman collection**?

In Postman, I click "Get new Access token" and yet it does not show how Postman gets it - what type of request, what payload - almost nothing. That is why I am asking this question. Because I cannot replay the request of getting new access token in my Node app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667206/mock-postman-request-into-axios